# sprite size libgdx android

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

I created 5 sprites using libgdx library, then want to assign the different size to all of them between 0 to 10 and then move from left to right.  5 sprite is succussfully created but the problem is in the size. i tried the S.nextInt(10). but its not working.
 Also i want to create all the sprites between 100-200 height. how to do it?

```
    int number = 5;
    sprite = new Sprite[number];

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        sprite[i] = new Sprite(texture);
        int size = S.nextInt(10);
        sprite[i].setSize(size, size);
        speed = S.nextInt(2);
        sprite[i].setPosition(speed, 100);
    }


    batch.begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        sprite[i].draw(batch);
    }

    batch.end();
```

Comment: nextInt(10) gives a random int between 0 and 10, which would be the pixel size of your image. Have you tried nextInt(100)+100?

Comment: nextInt(10) is the size of sprite and nextInt(100)+100 value is tried in the height but every time the rendering process is rerenderend is done then the value is updated. like if the default fps is 25 then the rendering process is done 25 times in one second so the value is changed 25 times in one second which gives weired behaviour.

Comment: Are you creating your sprites in the render loop? If you create them and set their sizes in the create() method and run your drawing loop in the render() method, the sizes should remain constant.

Comment: yeah, u r rite i am creating the sprites in the render loop. the probs is that i am loading the spritesheet like this http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteAnimation. then assign the texture region currentframe to sprite. so i have to create sprite in render loop. is there better way of doing it? may be i am going in wrong way?

Comment: In the SpriteAnimation example, you load a texture and then draw a region of that texture with `currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);`. `stateTime` is compared to the rendering speed you specify at initialization, and a `TextureRegion` keyframe is selected that can be drawn as a Sprite. You can use the spritesheet and draw its keyframes exactly as shown in the example linked, with its creation in the `create()` method and the rendering of individual frames in the `render()` method. The (50, 50) in the example is an arbitrary position that you can change to anything.